# Splitting up controller in multiple js files

Tags: sapui5

I was wondering how to go about splitting up a controller in multiple JavaScript-files. I currently have a controller which has about 5000+ lines and it is rather frustrating to navigate through it. Any suggestions how to get started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach is to set up some hierarchy between your controllers and use inheritance between the controllers. Move the logic which is used by several controllers to one `BaseController.js`.

For example you can set up a `BaseController.js` which extend from `sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller`:

```js
sap.ui.define([ "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller" ], function(Controller) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("BaseController", {

        someBaseFunction : function() {
            // Do something
        },

    });

});
```

And the in another controller e.g. `App.controller.js` extend from your `BaseController.js`:

```js
sap.ui.define(["%PATH_TO_YOUR_BASE_CONTROLLER%/BaseController",

], function(BaseController) {
    "use strict";

    return BaseController.extend("%PATH_TO_YOUR_APP", {

        onInit : function() {
            // Call function from BaseController.js
            this.someFunction();
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: I have 4 controllers for 1 view and I am currently using following solution. My Main controller is extending subcontroller3, subcontroller3 is extending subcontroller2 and subcontroller2 is then extending subcontroller1. This works, but it doesn't seem like a proper solution. Can I somehow extend the main controller to all 3 subcontrollers?

Comment: No, I think this is not possible. One ui5 Control can only extend always one other control. So the approach you have chosen is the proper solution to do that..

Comment: What you can try is to extend controllers prototype with all your subcontrollers. Anyways Inheritance is not neccessarily the best way to organize code... I found that esp. with deep inheritance chains it can make things overly complex. You might be better off with a mixin approach.

Comment: @cschuff That's right but the Ui5 framework does not offer a good way of splitting code. 

Splitting the code into several classes and then require the code inline can also construct pitfalls, because you never know which class / controllers requires your code. In big projects this also cause problems.

Comment: @FrancescoIannazzo JS itself does offer possibilities to split up code. Check this article on mixins for example: https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/a-fresh-look-at-javascript-mixins/

Comment: @cschuff Thanks for the article , I will go through it. Looks interesting.

Answer (score 5):

You can start with several approaches:

1. Use "Mixin" pattern
2. Split your logic up to several "classes" and put them to separate AMD modules, then just "require" them and use in your controller

Mixin can be implemented as an **AMD module** which just returns **JSON** object with all needed functions. In order to inject it to the controller, just make use of **jQuery.extend** method to enhance the controller's object with mixin.

Answer (score 2):

This question would lead to somewhat opinionated answers but *generally*, you could start off by:

- Asking yourself whether it is possible to reduce the 5k+ LOC first. E.g.:

  - Make sure you were not reinventing the wheels what UI5 already
    supports out-of-the-box such as [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47603778/5846045), parsing, and validating model data.
  - Consider to take more declarative approaches that UI5 offers, such as [application descriptor](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/be0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da), simple [expression bindings](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0), two-way [data binding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/e5310932a71f42daa41f3a6143efca9c), splitting the view into small [fragments](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/234320f8d8ee45b39c60893116d60351) / [views](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/df8c9c3d79b54c928855162bafcd88ee) having their own controller if reasonable ([separating concerns](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)), etc.
- Analyzing your code to embrace *[composition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48110214/5846045) over [inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48109987/splitting-up-controller-in-multiple-js-files#comment83197531_48110591)* ([short intro](https://youtu.be/wfMtDGfHWpA))

I'd also encourage to write some regression [tests](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/2696ab50faad458f9b4027ec2f9b884d) before you start.