# sap.m.Select - Bind key as Integer

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am using `sap.m.Select` as a select option for a user and it looks like this:

```
<Select
    forceSelection="false"
    selectedKey="{Priority}"
    items="{
        path: '/PRIORITY_DDSet',
        formatter: '.formatter.convert',
        sorter: {
            path: 'Value'
        }
    }"
>
    <core:Item
        key="{
            path:'Id',
            formatter: '.formatter.convert',
            type: 'Integer'
        }"
        text="{Value}"
    />
</Select>
```

As a model, `ODataModel` is used. The problem is: when change on the `sap.m.Select` happens, the string key is bound to the OData model like this:

[image]

However, the definition of the OData model states, that `Priority` should be of type `Integer`.

As you can see in the definition of the `Select`, I tried to use `formatter` for the `key` as well as the type `Integer`. I also tried to use `sap.ui.model.type.Integer` as a type but without success. I checked, and the formatter function is called only when loading the `Select`. When selection is changed in the `Select`, the formatter function is not called.

Is there a way to do this in XML? Or do I need to code this e.g. in selection changed event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove formatters and add `type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Integer'` to selectedKey:

```
<Select 
    forceSelection="false" 
    selectedKey="{path: 'Priority', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Integer'}"
    items="{ path: '/PRIORITY_DDSet', sorter: { path: 'Value' } }">
    <core:Item 
        key="{path:'Id'}" 
        text="{Value}"/>
</Select>
```

I'm not sure if that's the reason but value of the `Priority` property can be used without any extra coding like type conversion to save with e.g. `ODataModel.submitChanges()`

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the type of the `Priority` value has changed to string is because the `Id` inside the `key` binding has the type `Edm.String`. If the `Priority` has the type `Edm.Int32`, use the corresponding binding type [`sap.ui.model.odata.type.Int32`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.type.Int32) instead of the regular `sap.ui.model.type.Integer`:

```
<Select
  forceSelection="false"
  selectedKey="{
    path: 'Priority',
    type: 'sap.ui.model.odata.type.Int32'
  }"
  items="{
    path: '/PRIORITY_DDSet',
    sorter: {
      path: 'Value'
    }
  }">
  <core:Item
    key="{Id}"
    text="{Value}"/>
</Select>
```

[List of other possible OData types](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/333a9dac5a614b1590c61916c9cecbf5)

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47603778/5846045), UI5 offers [OData types](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.type) for conversion of data representation whereas two-way data binding support is kept in contrast to the `formatter`. That is why your formatter function was not called when selection was changed.