# Initial Date/Time in SAPUI5 Datepicker

Tags: sapui5, datetimepicker

I've a problem. I'm using the Datepicker like this:

```
<DateTimePicker id="pickerStartTime" value="{CURRENT>/StartTime}" valueLiveUpdate="true" displayFormat="dd.MM.yy HH:mm" valueFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" />
```

On RouteMatched i want to display the current Date and Time.

```
_onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {
    this.oModelCurrent.setProperty("/", {
        Name: "",
        StartTime: new Date(),
        Duration: "30",
        ShuntReason: "",
    });
}
```

My problem is the displayFormat. The DateTimePicker shows e.g.

> Thu Apr 26 2018 11:42:00 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)

and not the displayFormat `dd.MM.yy HH:mm`. After selecting a Date/Time from Datepicker everything is fine.

I've tried to put the date like below in the model:

```
StartTime: moment().format("DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm")
```

But that results in a Invalid Date.

Comment: Make use of sap.ui.model.type.Date while doing binding, this is better approach.

Comment: Thx it's working.
`<DateTimePicker width="100%" value="{path : 'CURRENT>/StartTime', type : 'sap.ui.model.type.DateTime', formatOptions:{ pattern : 'dd.MM.YYY, HH:mm'}}" valueLiveUpdate="true" valueFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" />`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Add Date / Time from OData Service Correctly to UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47593990/how-to-add-date-time-from-odata-service-correctly-to-ui)