# How to Display a Specific Control Based on Some Value?

Tags: sapui5

I have the following code:

```xml
<t:template>
  <Text text="{path: 'dateday', formatter:'.formatdate'}"/>
</t:template>

<t:template>
  <Text text="{path: 'datetime', formatter:'.formatime'}"/>
</t:template>
```

And I need to display the second template only if the 'dateday' value is `null`, `undefined` or empty.

Any idea how to achieve this in XML?

Comment: Off-topic but if the `datetime` is coming from an OData service, you might want to use a [built-in type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47603778/) instead of a custom formatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All controls can be displayed or hidden via the property `visible` (or [setVisible](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.Control/methods/setVisible)).
Combine it with [expression binding](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0) and the second Text is only visible when `dateday` value is **not** [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

```xml
<Text
  text="{
    path: 'datetime',
    formatter:'.formatime'
  }"
  visible="{= !!${dateday}}"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok so I figured it out using 'visible' property

```
<t:template visible="{= ${/dateday} !== null }">
<Text text="{path: 'dateday', formatter:'.formatday'}"/>
</t:template>

<t:template visible="{= ${/dateday} === null }">
<Text text="{path: 'datetime', formatter:'.formatime'}"/>
</t:template>
```

Hope it can help others :P