# Formatting/Parsing Time from Odata

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

I am trying to format this Time coming from ODATA, in the XML it looks like this: PT00H00M00S

I tried first creating a function I found online: Seems promising but.....I wans't sure how to use in in the VIEW.XML, is somebody could advise I would appreciate. I just started with UI5.

```
    return Controller.extend("zTESTJK1.zTESTJK1.controller.Main", {

    Time: function (val) {
        if (val) {
            val = val.replace(/^PT/, '').replace(/S$/, '');
            val = val.replace('H', ':').replace('M', ':');

            var multipler = 60 * 60;
            var result = 0;
            val.split(':').forEach(function (token) {
                result += token * multipler;
                multipler = multipler / 60;
            });
            var timeinmiliseconds = result * 1000;

            var timeFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getTimeInstance({
                pattern: "KK:mm:ss a"
            });
            var TZOffsetMs = new Date(0).getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;
            return timeFormat.format(new Date(timeinmiliseconds + TZOffsetMs));
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I tried to do it this way too but it won't work either:
[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47603778/5846045