# Date format issue in UI5

Tags: sapui5

I have a Odata service which brings back audit date and time in following pattern

AUDIT_Date : Sun Nov 23 -4713 16:07:02 GMT-0752 (Pacific Standard Time)

AUDIT_time: :
ms:0
__edmType: "Edm.Time"

in metadata I see the format as :

```
<d:AUDIT_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">0000-00-00T00:00:00.0000000</d:AUDIT_DATE>

<d:AUDIT_TIME m:type="Edm.Time">PT0H0M0S</d:AUDIT_TIME>
```

I am trying to create a new record and while doing so I need to pass current date and time in those fields. I saw some blogs on date formats but none is giving me clear example on how I should solve this issue.

```
       The data object I am trying to pass to OdataModel.create is "parts"
       and need to pass 
       parts.Audit_date = "current date"
       parts.Audit_Time = "current time" in those formats.
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47603778/5846045

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, I understand date formatting better now. Also, my issue got resolved with the other blog that was shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example:

```
parts.Audit_date = "/Date(1354665600000)/";
parts.Audit_Time = "PT11H00M00S";
```

the date is ms since 1970 and the time is 11 hours 0 minutes and 0 seconds : )

this is the best blog to find information about edm dates and times in my opinion:
https://blogs.sap.com/2013/04/28/working-with-odata-dates/